# image is not showing in django

Tags: python, django

all the data from models is visible except images..tried everthing .. pillow is preinstalled.. static url and root are right.. but cant figure out whats wrong with images..

html..

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="profile-image">
                            <img src="{{About.image}}" alt="profile photo">
                        </div><!-- end profile-image -->
                    </div><!-- end col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="about-text">
                            <p> {{ About.first.desc}}</p>
```

models.py

```
      from django.db import models
         import datetime
         # Create your models here.
          class About(models.Model):
          image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pics')
          desc  = models.TextField()
```

settings.py

```
               STATIC_URL = '/static/'
               STATICFILES_DIRS =[
                         os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'portfolio/static')
                        ]
                      STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

                 MEDIA_URL  ='/media/'
                 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

project urls.py

```
     from django.contrib import admin
      from django.urls import path,include
      from django.conf import settings
     from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns = [

path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('home/', include("home.urls")),
path('blog/', include("blog.urls")),


   ]
   urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = 
       settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

Comment: Are you serving your media files correctly? Are you seeing the image in the media folder? Lets see your urls

Comment: hi i hvave shared project urls.py please check

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<div class="profile-image">
    <img src="{{About.image.url}}" alt="profile photo">
</div>
```

and make sure you're urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
 <your url patterns here> 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: hi i have shared project urls.py please check

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `.url` after the image src, try:

```
<img src="{{About.imsge.url}}" alt="profile photo">
```

For more info check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)

change your urls.py like this:

```
    urlpatterns = [

path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('home/', include("home.urls")),
path('blog/', include("blog.urls")),


   ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = 
       settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

Comment: Can i see your urls.py from your project folder ? Maybe you forgot to add "+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)" to the urlpatterns

Comment: hi i hvave shared project urls.py please check